# Real analysis: $\epsilon-N$ proof

Tags: real-analysis

Here's my proof for the fact that the sequence $\frac{n+6}{n^2-7}$ converges to $0$. Can someone verify it?

Let $\epsilon > 0$.
 Pick N = $max\{2, \frac{7}{\epsilon}\}$.

Then, if $n > N$, $\left|\frac{n+6}{n^2-6}\right| = \frac{n+6}{n^2-6}$, since $n > 2$.

Now, $\frac{n+6}{n^2 - 6} \leq \frac{7n}{n^2} = \frac{7}{n} \leq \epsilon$.

This completes the proof.

Comment: And that's all she wrote. Lovely proof.

Answer (score 0):

You proof is correct. (There is a minor typo, the denominator should be $n^2-7$ instead of $n^2-6$)